# What counts as "helping slay an elemental" for a Ring of Elemental Command?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters

The various *Rings of Elemental Command* in the DMG (p. 190) all have basic abilities that start working as soon as you attune them, but there are other abilities that only start working if you "help slay [an] elemental" of the same type that the ring commands.

As the DM of our current campaign, I'm considering having one of these rings be available to the group, but I'm curious how strict I should be in the interpretation of that "help slay" part. Most of the scenarios I can think of boil down to a version of:

**Does dominating an elemental that's otherwise been minding its own business and having it stand between me and (subsequently get eaten by) the dragon that's chasing me count as "helping slay" that elemental?**

My inclination is that this is perfectly acceptable but I'm curious if there's a rules clarification on what counts as "slaying" in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## This is up to DM discretion.

As with much of 5e, this is left up to DM discretion. I personally think the scenario you present is a perfectly legitimate way of "help[ing] slay" an elemental of the appropriate type.

When I saw the question title, I thought you were going to ask about scenarios where the party had slain an elemental, but the PC attuned to the ring had (likely through rotten dice rolls) not actually directly contributed to the elemental's death.  As long as that character was making an earnest effort to help the party, I'd still consider them to have helped slay the elemental.  They probably helped in some way, even if indirect.